# Catch events firebird with nodejs is not working

Tags: node.js, events, ubuntu-14.04, firebird

I installed nodejs with NVM to be able to use different versions.

And then installed Firebird in accordance with [these instructions](http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/ubusetup.html).

Later I followed the instructions at the bottom of [this tutorial](http://www.king-foo.com/2011/07/catch-firebird-events-with-node-js/) to catch events.

Basically it adds a trigger that makes the "post_event".

```
SQL> SET TERM !! ;
SQL> CREATE TRIGGER new_employee_event FOR employee
CON> ACTIVE
CON> AFTER UPDATE
CON> AS
CON> BEGIN
CON> POST_EVENT 'update_employee';
CON> END!!
SQL> SET TERM ; !!
```

Here is the code that i use for listen events:

```
var fb  = require("firebird");
var http=require('http');
var sys=require('sys');
var con = fb.createConnection();

con.connectSync('localhost:/var/lib/firebird/2.5/data/employee.fdb','sysdba','masterkey','');
con.addFBevent("update_employee");
con.on("fbevent",function(event,count){

    var rows = null;
    rows = con.querySync("select * from EMPLOYEE WHERE EMP_NO = 145;").fetchSync(1,true);
    con.commitSync();
    console.log("An Employee record has been updated");
    console.log(rows);

});

WaitForFinish(function(){ return finished; },
  function(){
       con.disconnect();
       CleanUp();
       test.done();
  }, 20000);

var finished = false;

function WaitForFinish(finished,clean,timeout){
  var timedout = false;
  var tid = setTimeout(function(){
    timedout = true;
  },timeout);
  process.nextTick(function loop(){
     if(finished.call()||timedout){
       clearTimeout(tid);
       clean.call();
     }
     else process.nextTick(loop);
  });
}
```

And this is the code I use to generate an event.

```
var fb  = require("firebird");
sys = require("sys");
var con = fb.createConnection();
con.connectSync('localhost:/var/lib/firebird/2.5/data/employee.fdb','SYSDBA','masterkey','');
con.querySync("UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET SALARY = 32004 WHERE EMP_NO = 145 ");
con.commitSync();
var res = con.querySync("select * from EMPLOYEE WHERE EMP_NO = 145" );
var rows = res.fetchSync("all",true);
console.log(sys.inspect(rows));
```

My node version is:

```
node -v
v0.12.13
```

My OS is:

```
uname -r
4.2.0-35-generic
```

The problem is that simply does not work. No error.

I do not know more to do. I need to catch events for a project.

Answer (score 1):

In Firebird a connection needs to subscribe on an event by name, no subscription means no notification. You are registering for event `update_employee`, while the event posted from the trigger is `employee_updated`. So you never get a notification, because there is no event with name `update_employee`.

You need to change your code to

```
con.addFBevent("employee_updated"); // <-- event name used in trigger
con.on("fbevent", function(event,count){
    // ... your event handling
});
```

As far as I can tell from [the documentation](https://github.com/xdenser/node-firebird-libfbclient), there is only one event handler function, so if you want to handle multiple events, you need to add logic based on `event` (which is the name of the event).

Comment: Mark thanks for answering my question.  
The error you mention is a typical "cut & paste" error when I created this post.  
I edited the question to someone else not observe the same error.  
Many thanks.

Comment: @AlePaciotti so, you still have the problem even after changing the event name?

Comment: Yes @MarkRotteveel. The same problem.

Comment: @AlePaciotti I'm not familiar with node itself, but I will see if I can reproduce the problem to see if I can find how to fix it.

Comment: Mark .. that would be too good for me!
If you want, I tell you my nitrous.io username and password.
My email is Alejandro point paciotti at gmail dot com.

Comment: @AlePaciotti Not necessary thanks. However it might be a few days before I actually have time to look at it.

Comment: Marc No problem, I'll be waiting.